# How to send requests to a downloaded html file

Tags: python, request

I have a .html file downloaded and want to send a request to this file to grab it's content.

However, if I do the following:

```
import requests
html_file  = "/user/some_html.html"
r = requests.get(html_file)
```

Gives the following error:

> Invalid URL 'some_html.html': No schema supplied.

If I add a schema I get the following error:

> HTTPConnectionPool(host='some_html.html', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url:

I want to know how to specifically send a request to a html file when it's downloaded.

Comment: What scheme did you try adding? The only thing that might work with a local file is `file://`,  but why are you trying to open this with `requests.get` rather than just using `open`?

Comment: You are accessing html file from local directory. get() method uses HTTPConnection and port to access data from website not a local directory. To access file from local directory using get() method use Xampp or Wampp.

Comment: I just checked, and `requests` by itself does not support `file://` URLs. There are available adapters you can install to add that support, but you're better off just opening local files normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing html file from local directory. `get()` method uses `HTTPConnection` and port 80 to access data from website not a local directory. To access file from local directory using `get()` method use Xampp or Wampp.
for accessing file from local directory you can use `open()` while `requests.get()` is for accessing file from `Port 80` using http Connection in simple word from internet not local directory

```
import requests
html_file  = "/user/some_html.html"
t=open(html_file, "r")
for v in t.readlines():
  print(v)
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't "send a request to a html file". Instead, you can send a request to a HTTP server on the internet which will return a response with the contents of a html file.

The file itself knows nothing about "requests". If you have the file stored locally and want to do something with it, then you can open it just like any other file.

If you are interested in learning more about the request and response model, I suggest you try a something like

```
response = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

You should also read about HTTP and requests and responses to better understand how this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting up a **local server** to your html file.
If you use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), you can install **[Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer)** by Ritwick Dey.

Then you do as follows:

1 - Make the first request and save the html content into a .html file:

## my_req.py

```
import requests

file_path = './'
file_name = 'my_file'

url = "https://www.qwant.com/"

response = requests.request("GET", url)

w = open(file_path + file_name + '.html', 'w')
w.write(response.text)
```

2 - With Live Server installed on [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), click on **my_file.html** and then click on **Go Live**.

[image: Go Live]

and

3 - Now you can **make a request** to your **local http** schema:

## second request

```
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:5500/my_file.html"

response = requests.request("GET", url)

print(response.text)
```

And, tcharan!! do what you need to do.

On a crawler work, I had one situation where there was a difference between the content displayed on the website and the content retrieved with the **response.text** so the xpaths did not were the same as on the website, so I needed to download the content, making a local html file, and get the new ones xpaths to get the info that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from requests_html import HTML
with open("htmlfile.html") as htmlfile:
    sourcecode = htmlfile.read()
    parsedHtml = HTML(html=sourcecode)
print(parsedHtml)
```

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please add some description explaining what is does and how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.